# CSS parse error on a[href=#s] selector

Tags: css, syntax, syntax-error, parse-error

I completed my Reddit project (CSS) for our subreddit of about 1000 people. All works fine and dandy but wait, I try to validate it in w3schools and it throws up this:

http://pastebin.com/VfSCrym8

If you need my CSS file here you go... I'm stuck with this problem

http://pastebin.com/dhyCPe3w

Oh and I tried uploading it on Reddit also and it comes up with a similar variant of the same error:

> [line 173] syntax error: "Selector: Unexpected HASH. [173:8: #s]"

```css
a[href=#s], a[href=/s] { /*...*/ }
```

If you can fix this horrible error then I am forever in debted to you! If you need the Html file also to rectify it then say

EDIT:

Thanks guys,

Threw up this error also:

> [line 1825] syntax error: "Selector: Unexpected HASH. [1825:30: > #icon-]"

```css
.side .md blockquote a[href*=#icon-]:before {
```

Tried the `""` but didn't work?

Comment: I believe I tried it with the quotes yesterday, ill try again and see. Sorry yes w3.ord. Its like 5am here and my brain isnt functioning too well.

Comment: Why are you using w3schools to validate anything?? Use [`W3C's CSS Validation service`](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/). W3Schools is a terrible resource. You do need quotes, by the way.

Comment: @user3302972 Using the quotes works. You gotta get 'em all though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the

```
href="#s"
```

There is also an extra } on line 317

The opacity stuff is likely because it is an IE hack

Validators check for errors compared to the W3 standard, so you have to take it with a grain of salt. Much of this CSS will still work. But the CSS selectors need to be in quotes to be correct (it may still work in your browser)

EDIT: And as mentioned by user2864740 - [use the W3 CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator)

Comment: Oh sweet thanks :)
EDIT: Nearly finished but it threw up this:

[line 1825] syntax error: "Selector: Unexpected HASH. [1825:30: #icon-]"
 .side .md blockquote a[href*=#icon-]:before {

I tried putting the quotations around the # and after the icon or the - and neither work...?

Comment: @user3302972 Just as with above .. `a[href*="#icon-"]`. Go back to the rules for valid CSS identifiers to see if quotes can be omitted for values. Or, when in doubt, quote. (The quotes go around the *entire* value.)

Comment: @user3302972 `a[href*=#icon-]` was reported, I suggested `a[href*="#icon-"]` as it *will* work - are there perhaps two (or more) such rules on the same line?

Comment: Ugh this is not my day. I did that... Haha but I edited the wrong line of code -_-

Answer (score 0):

The selector values need to be quoted (with single or double quotes) as so

```
a[href="#s"], a[href='/s']
```

because the neither `#s` nor `/s` follow the rules for CSS a [identifier token](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#token-diagrams) and thus strings must be used.

---

An CSS identifier token is in the form, escapes permitted:

```
-?[a-zA-Z_{Non-ASCII}][a-zA-Z0-9_{Non-ASCII}]
```

The original CSS syntax is invalid because # (and /) *are* ASCII, but are not in the approved set.

---

I recommend using the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator), if not doing so; note that W3C is *not related* to W3 Schools.